# How do I set streetView in my mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

can my MapView show Google map tiles at streetView level if the emulator cannot connect to the internet? Because my code below aint working!!

```
package com.HelloMapView;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class HelloMapView extends MapActivity {
    private static MapController myMapController = null;
    private static GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(25.24243399999999 * 1E6),(int)(55.30611937301637 * 1E6));

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.displayZoomControls(false);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setFocusable(true);
        myMapController = mapView.getController();
        myMapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
        myMapController.setZoom(15);
        // mapView.invalidate();
        // mapView.setFocusable(true);
        myMapController.setCenter(geoPoint);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint,"abc","");
        itemizedOverlay.addoverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        //mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);




    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The other class that extends ItemizedOverlay

```
package com.HelloMapView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlay=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlay.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlay.size();
    }
    public void addoverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
    {
        mOverlay.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

}
```

Somebody please lend me a hand. Plus eclipse says setStreetView is deprecated and is not supported anymore. I dont know if I am alone in this because other forums are saying my problem is that i should use setStreetView from the MapView class. But it is deprecated, I dont know if they know this or not!! Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is deprecated, but setStreetView is not what it seems anyway, it only showed a indicator whether street view tiles "were" available for a specific street, it did not not actually show street view tiles.

Google does not expose a way to get the streeview camera for the android API, you may only show satellite or 2d map view. This plus a lot of other features sadly are not available from Google Maps for our use.

And for the other two modes you always need an internet connection

Reference [setStreetView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setStreetView%28boolean%29)

Notice that it says *Control whether Street View availability (blue outlines) is shown on the map* in other words it would draw a blue outline around streets that you could obtain street view for, well at least for google maps, but not via the Android API